# How do i access private methods of a model/concern from an active job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activejob, activesupport-concern

Is it possible?
I tried calling it from foo_model where i have included the concern but i keep getting, **NoMethodError: private method 'foo_def' called foo_model**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Q&A:
Why have i not created a concern in jobs?
I need to use 5-6 methods from the model/concern. It will be against DRY principles if i have the same code in two different concerns.

Comment: Private methods are called "private" for a reason. They are implementation detail, none of anybody's business. If you _need_ to call a private method, then you either: a) misclassified it as private (should be part of public api instead) or b) want to commit terrible crimes against OO design by breaking encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev for the (b) warning. I tweaked my code flow.

Answer (score 1):

You can always call private methods using [#send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send): `instance.send(:private_method, arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: I tried this & It works but i will not be calling private methods like this.